# One user in UNIX group can run azcopy the other user in the group cannot

Tags: bash, rhel

Two users `foobar` and `foobiz` are in the same RH Linux group

cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,4  |  grep ^foo

`foobar:10`

`foobiz:10`

foobar can run **azcopy**

$ azcopy --version

`azcopy version 10.3.4`

foobiz cannot run **azcopy**

$ azcopy --version

`-bash: azcopy: command not found`

Question: How can foobiz run `azcopy`

Comment: They have different values of `$PATH`. Check their shell's initialization scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on @kusalananda's answer:

The `PATH` environment variable defines where the users shell can find binaries.

so use this command to examine the PATH:

`echo $PATH`

Now if you'd use the command `which` you can find where that binary is located'

`which azcopy`

Then the other user can add the Directory leading up to that binary to his PATH with:

`export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar/bla`

And he probably wants to add that command to his `.bash_profile` to make that change permanent.

Comment: Also confirm group executable permission on `azcopy` so foobiz can run the command.